# Registering linux device: file_operations vs device_attribute

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to register a char device, and I'm not sure what is the difference between the `file_opreation`, that is used when registering the device with [register_chrdev](https://www.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/kernel-api/re941.html), and the `device_attribute`, that is used when creating the device with [device_create_file](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/device-drivers/API-device-create-file.html).

Both of those structs hold functions, that should be called when read&write operations are preformed on the device. So what is the difference between them? can I implement the functions only for one of them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface where you use the functions are different. device_attribute is specific to sysfs and file_operations has a larger scope. If you can provide all the required functionalities and interface to your device through just show and store operations on sysfs entries, you can choose device_Attribute.

Have a look at the members of both the structures. Operations like seek, ioctl, mmap, flush can only be supported through file_operations.

May be, in short, file_operations in general are associated with **device nodes** in /dev and device_attributes with special files in /sys